# R - Lubridate: Why does one function call work, but not the other?

Tags: r, lubridate

Why does this work (using a column name):

```
> dataset$time <- dmy_hms(dataset$Timestamp)
```

But not this (using a column index):

```
> dataset$time <- dmy_hms(dataset[,1])
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Here's what column one of the data looks like:

```
> dataset[,1]
# A tibble: 228 x 1
             Timestamp
                 <chr>
 1 01/01/1970 00:00:30
 2 01/01/1970 00:01:00
 3 01/01/1970 00:01:30
 4 01/01/1970 00:02:00
 5 01/01/1970 00:02:30
 6 01/01/1970 00:03:00
 7 01/01/1970 00:03:30
 8 01/01/1970 00:04:00
 9 01/01/1970 00:04:30
10 01/01/1970 00:05:00
# ... with 218 more rows
```

What gives?

Comment: probably because `dataset[,1]` is a tibble, while `dataset$Timestamp` is a vector

Comment: I suspect you are right. Hmmmm.